# Use grep to fetch all binary values that don't contain sub-string like '1001'

Tags: grep

I would like to find a grep that extracts all "words" of 0 and 1 from the text file that do not contain the substring 1001.
For example, in the file "1110 example 11 10010000 000000"
it should return 1110,11,000000.

Comment: Is this an assignment for us? but we are not accepting assignments or tasks to do. If you have a question please clarify what is your problem so we can help you on that.

Comment: Have you considered doing a positive match for 0,1-words and then a consecutive negative match for 1001?

Comment: You also need to decide if you want the "words" output one per line, just one output line (with each word separated by commas), or one output line per input line (also separated by commas).   The first would be easy to do with `grep` alone, the second with `grep` and `paste`.  the third would be easy in `awk` or `perl`.

Comment: Why do you suppress the word "example"? Because the binary representaion of the "e" character contains the search sequence?

Comment: those are not binary values

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
tr '\n' ' ' |
    tr ' ' '\n' |
    grep -Fv '1001' |
    grep -E '^[01]+$'
```

- Separate each word into one line with `tr`.
- Exclude `1001` from each line with `grep -Fv`.
- Search lines that contain only `0` or `1` with `grep -E`.